joining two xsd schemes generated from xml that has different target namespaces
I have a problem: when I generate from XML to XSD i get two schemes, because i have different target namespaces. Now I need to join them together but I always get error that it cannot access the file from the second scheme. Can anyone help me with it? I'm a beginner at this.
This is my XML:
<Theater xmlns="http://example.com/theater" xmlns:show="http://example.com/show">
<Opera>
    <Title>Carmen</Title>
    <Date>2024-12-01</Date>
    <Duration>180</Duration>
    <Location>
        <TheaterName>National Opera</TheaterName>
        <City>Vilnius</City>
    </Location>
    <Cast>
        <show:Performer role="Lead" age="35">
            <Name>Simonas Kliava</Name>
            <Character>Don José</Character>
            <Salary>1000.50</Salary>
        </show:Performer>
        <show:Performer role="Supporting" age="30">
            <Name>Aušra Kriaunaitė</Name>
            <Character>Carmen</Character>
            <Salary>850.00</Salary>
        </show:Performer>
    </Cast>
    <Tickets>
         <Ticket>
            <Price currency="EUR">50.00</Price>
            <Section>Balcony</Section>
            <Row>3</Row>
            <Seat>12</Seat>
        </Ticket>
        <Ticket>
        <Price currency="EUR">80.00</Price>
            <Section>Orchestra</Section>
            <Row>1</Row>
            <Seat>8</Seat>
        </Ticket>
    </Tickets>
</Opera>

<Ballet>
    <Title>Spragtukas</Title>
    <Date>2024-12-23</Date>
    <Duration>120</Duration>
    <Location>
        <TheaterName>National Ballet</TheaterName>
        <City>Kaunas</City>
    </Location>
    <Cast>
        <show:Performer role="Lead" age="28">
            <Name>Viktoras Žukauskas</Name>
            <Character>The Nutcracker</Character>
            <Salary>1200.75</Salary>
        </show:Performer>
    </Cast>
    <Tickets>
        <Ticket>
        <Price currency="EUR">60.00</Price>
            <Section>Balcony</Section>
            <Row>4</Row>
            <Seat>15</Seat>
        </Ticket>
        <Ticket>
        <Price currency="EUR">100.00</Price>
            <Section>Orchestra</Section>
            <Row>2</Row>
            <Seat>5</Seat>
        </Ticket>
    </Tickets>
</Ballet>

This is my scheme0:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid Technologies Online Tools 1.0 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<xs:schema xmlns:show="http://example.com/show" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://example.com/theater" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:import schemaLocation="schema1.xsd" namespace="http://example.com/show" />
  <xs:element name="Theater">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Opera">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Date" type="xs:date" />
              <xs:element name="Duration" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
              <xs:element name="Location">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="TheaterName" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Cast">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="show:Performer" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Tickets">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Ticket">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="Price">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:simpleContent>
                                <xs:extension base="xs:decimal">
                                  <xs:attribute name="currency" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                </xs:extension>
                              </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                          <xs:element name="Section" type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element name="Row" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
                          <xs:element name="Seat" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Ballet">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Date" type="xs:date" />
              <xs:element name="Duration" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
              <xs:element name="Location">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="TheaterName" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Cast">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="show:Performer" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Tickets">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Ticket">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="Price">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:simpleContent>
                                <xs:extension base="xs:decimal">
                                  <xs:attribute name="currency" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                </xs:extension>
                              </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                          <xs:element name="Section" type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element name="Row" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
                          <xs:element name="Seat" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="Character" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="Salary" type="xs:decimal" />
</xs:schema>

This is my scheme1:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid Technologies Online Tools 1.0 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://example.com/show" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://example.com/show" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:import schemaLocation="schema0.xsd" namespace="http://example.com/theater" />
  <xs:element name="Performer">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element xmlns:q1="http://example.com/theater" ref="q1:Name" />
        <xs:element xmlns:q2="http://example.com/theater" ref="q2:Character" />
        <xs:element xmlns:q3="http://example.com/theater" ref="q3:Salary" />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="role" type="xs:string" use="required" />
      <xs:attribute name="age" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>

Please don't be harsh I may be stupid... I tried the include method but I cannot get it to work. I'm also using online editor I'm not saving any files to computer

I think the problem is specific to the "online editor" you are using. You need to find out how it handles cross-file references, assuming it does so at all.
